# Problems with components after npm run build

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuetify.js, vue-cli

Using Vue-cli plugin I've created small SPA application with Vuetify component framework. When I was running in dev mode everything was fine but in production mode there was problem with components `'installComponents' has already been declared`

Then I've found out that this was connected with *Tree shaking* option that only worksi with webpack 4 in production mode. Or to be more precise including components that you need, instead of getting all of them.

So, instead of registering  every single component I tried to use  vuetify-loader to automatize "*a la carte components*" but I it seems that I'm missing something.

my plugins/vuetify.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'
import 'vuetify/src/stylus/app.styl'

Vue.use(Vuetify)
```

And my vue.config.js is like this

```
const VuetifyLoaderPlugin = require('vuetify-loader/lib/plugin')
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new VuetifyLoaderPlugin()
    ]
  }
}
```

And main.js is like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import './plugins/vuetify'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store/store'
import axios from 'axios';

Vue.config.productionTip = false

//adding main path to baseurl
axios.defaults.baseURL = "";
// Global settings for Axios
Vue.prototype.$http = axios;


new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

And I'm still getting this error

```
Module parse failed: Identifier 'installComponents' has already been declared (35:7)
```

It's worth mentioning that my babel.config.js looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/app'
  ]
}
```

I'm using vue 2.5.21 and vuetify 1.3.0

**UPDATE**

I changed my vue.config.js with this lines

```
module.exports = {
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
        ? '/hr-map/'
        : '/vue-map/',
    chainWebpack: config => {
        config.module
            .rule('vue')
            .use('vue-loader')
            .loader('vue-loader')
            .tap(options => {
                // modify the options...
                return options
            })
    }
}
```

But now in production I'm getting rather strange error for my components

```
Uncaught TypeError: T(...)(...) is not a function
at Module.56d7 (VectorFeatures.vue:37)
at r (bootstrap:78)
at Object.0 (bootstrap:151)
at r (bootstrap:78)
at i (bootstrap:45)
at bootstrap:151
at bootstrap:151
```

[image]

I must say that when I'm in dev environment everything works fine.